# A question related to the Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, conditional-convergence

It's a well known result that the Alternating Harmonic Series : $$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + ... = \ln(2)$$ But, this is because of "Conditional Convergence". I saw somewhere that if you re-arrange the terms in the series like this : $$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4} +... = \frac{3}{2} \ln(2)$$ When I first saw it, my mind was blown. I couldn't accept it. How can the result change just by re-arranging the terms? My guess was that it is somewhat related to the $\mathbb{Z^+}$ paradox where the number of even integers is $\frac{1}{2}$ of all the numbers and $\frac{1}{3}$ when you arrange it in some other way(Not the theory but the logic behind it). Can anybody please explain why does the result of the Alternating Harmonic Series **change** when you re-arrange the terms. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: See [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4068) closely related question and its answers.

Comment: The really weird thing is that conditionally convergent things can be rearranged to converge to ANY number

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help :)